# .htaccess 301 RedirectMatch to a new channel

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, server

I would like to redirect from an old channel to a new one.

from

```
www.example.com/**oldchannel**/article/12345
```

to

```
www.example.com/**newchannel**/article/12345
```

Can someone tell me why this is not working?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldchannel/$ $1/newchannel$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^oldchannel/(.*)$ /newchannel/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Values need to be captured from pattern and back-references to be used in RHS target.

Comment: ok :) Perhaps you could also explain the following: below of the redirect I have the folling "RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]". When I try to access the /oldchannel/article/12345 I am redirected to /newchannel/article/123456?url=/oldchannel/article/123456..@anubhava

Comment: Have your rules in the given order above. Test after clearing browser cache.